# Shift image with EMGU cv in VB NET: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm trying to shift an image by, let's say, 100 pixels both on the X and the Y axis.
I understood that the best method to do it is by using the `WarpAffine` method, but I just can't get it to work. I've found a tutorial [here](https://learnopencv.com/image-rotation-and-translation-using-opencv/#image-translation) but it's in Python and C++ and the declaration of the `Mat` element is different. I just don't understand how to declare the trasformation matrix in VB.NET.

As stated in the link, the trasformation matrix should be as follows:
[image: formula]

In C++, you would declare it this way:

```
// tx and ty are the pixels to be shifted
float warp_values[] = { 1.0, 0.0, tx, 0.0, 1.0, ty };
Mat translation_matrix = Mat(2, 3, CV_32F, warp_values);
```

But in .NET, the `Mat` declaration does not accept an array of float (in .NET it would be `Single` or `Double` array), it just accept an `Integer` value called "Channels".

Infact, i just tried to translate the code to VB like this:

```
Dim warp_values As Single() = New Single(5) {1.0, 0, tx, 0, 1.0, ty}
Dim translation_matrix As New Mat(2, 3, CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32F, warp_values)
```

but i cannot proceed because I get an error `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called with these arguments` on the second line (in the Mat declaration).

So, I just need to know how to properly declare the Mat element in order to shift the image.
The documentation is quite poor and does not explain anything about this specific case, nor I can find any tutorial in VB or C# using EMGU.

Comment: `New Single(5)` five? why not six? -- please always debug your code before asking. this error happens before you even reach any OpenCV or Emgu code. those two libraries are not involved in the error.

Comment: That's how you declare an array in vb.net, because the explicit declaration is 0-based. So `New single(5)` will create an array of 6 elements. I debugged it and the array is created correctly.

Comment: Oh, that's counterintuitive. -- so you're saying the error happens in the `New Mat` call instead? first i'd like to recommend opencvsharp over emgu. opencvsharp is closer to opencv's api and it's better maintained (last I checked). there appears to be no constructor with that signature. pick one from https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm `step` may be `AUTO_STEP` (in C++ anyway) which might have had the value 0 at some time but I'll make no claims about today.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did not know about opencvsharp, I'll give a check, but this project is entirely based on emgu so if possible I would like to avoid rewriting it. The problem however is exactly this. There's no constructor in emgucv which accepts the translation data, like in opencv native libraries. So i just don't know how to tell the `WarpAffine` method that it should shift the image.

Comment: WarpAffine always takes a 2x3 matrix. you've got the correct values for a translation matrix. if all else fails, just create an empty/zeros matrix and then assign the elements individually. you can also start with a 3x3 matrix (`Mat.Eye(3,3,...)`) and then assign just the translation elements. you can then chop off the last row and pass the resulting 2x3 matrix to warpAffine (or give 3x3 to warpPerspective)

Comment: as for the error, I believe your intended Mat constructor is lacking further arguments (no issue with warpAffine). that's why I talked about `step`.